# Android - How to decode and decompile any APK file?

Tags: android, decode, decompiler, apk

I'm working on ads: my customers gave me some APK files of their Apps.
My work consists of inserting ad banners into them.
After closing the ad banners, these apps will run.

My question is: How to decode and decompile APK file?

Comment: Didn't try it yet but: http://rootzwiki.com/topic/1836-guide-how-to-decompile-an-apk-updated-w-guide/

Comment: @Bigflow : Exactly I want to decode APK files and edit them :-s

Comment: You can check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To decompile APK Use APKTool.
You can learn how APKTool works on http://www.decompileandroid.com/ or by reading [the documentation](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/).

Answer (score 17):

You can try this website http://www.decompileandroid.com
Just upload the .apk file and rest of it will be done by this site.

Comment: Uploading an apk is not possible anymore :( Now it only retrieves apks from the Play Store).

Comment: Looks to be down.