# Android - Error when building project to APK file using apktool

Tags: android, decode, apk

I have an APK file named: MyApp.apk. First I decode it using apktool:

```
apktool d MyApp.apk
```

It generates project folder: MyApp. Then I import it to Eclipse to edit it.
I create a new class as an Activity inside the MyApp project.
After finishing, I export the project to an APK file using apktool again:

```
apk b MyApp
```

It generates an APK file which I name Final_MyApp.apk. After, I sign it.
When I install Final_MyApp.apk using:

```
adb install Final_MyApp.apk
```

My application does not run. How can I fix it?

Comment: you always same question....

[Android - How to decode and decompile any APK file?][1]


[ANdroid - Run APK file after edited using apktool get error : [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975618/android-how-to-decode-and-decompile-any-apk-file
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994166/android-run-apk-file-after-edited-using-apktool-get-error-install-parse-fai

Comment: It's same Project but there are 3 problems. You don't see that ?

Answer (score 1):

`adb install` only installs your application on the device.
To start your application, you have to call the activity manager (am)

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

See this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567928/1321873.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot include your new activity into your android manifest file. That's why your APK does not run.

Also store your apk in C or D folder and try like this

```
adb install C:\Final_MyApp.apk
```