# Is there a way to list column names in an undocumented but allowed ContentProvider in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Suppose that you have AbcContentProvider which allows you to query/update it with it's content:// url.

Is it possible to see the names/values those can be updated or queried?

(This would be similar to "select * from table_abc" in an sql query or like "Show tables" from a database table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will help:

```
Uri u = // your CONTENT_URI
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver(uri, null, null, null, null, null);
Log.d(TAG, "listing column for uri=" + uri);
for (int i = 0; i<c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, "column " + i + "=" + c.getColumnName(i));
}
```

If the remote ContentProvider is not accepting a null projection:

1. If this is about an android internal ContentProvider: Read the android source code: http://source.android.com/
2. If this is about some other app: Decompile it and read the source code: [Android - How to decode and decompile any APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14975618/2331953)
3. You can brute force the list by querying with single element projection with a list of (random/generated) names

Comment: getContentresolver does not accept any parameters and when I modify this answer to call query function with null projection[] parameter, It throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Well, that's bad luck. Most ContentProvider do a `select *` when passing null as projection.

Comment: just added some ideas to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is related to a ContentProvider that is specific to Samsung Galaxy S3 android source (or any Samsung device). So I think I can't find the source for that..

Comment: Grab the providing apk and decompile it.

Comment: I don't have that api. You mean that I have to root the device and copy everything on the disk to my computer and try to decompile "Settings" application of my Samsung Galaxy S3?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant.

Comment: added brute forcing as option in the answer.

Comment: Even though this does not solve my problem, I am convinced that I cannot get the information I want without the methods like the ones you've shared: I mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you read Cursor docs? if not: getColumnCount() & getColumnName(idx)