# Android - compiled APK version change

Tags: android, apk

I have a an updated APK that another developer (hired 3rd party) compiled and sent my way to upload to my Google Play Developers Console to update the previous version. The issue is that he didn't change the version code before sending it to me and leaving the country for several months (without contact). I'm not able to change the manifest (as far as I know) and I get this error when I attempt to upload:

> Upload failed
>
> You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.

Any thoughts or suggestions as to the best way around this issue? I can't wait for the developer to get back in a few months as the app is only half usable at this point. I'm WAY out of my element - hence the hiring of a third party developer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use apktool for decompile the apk. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975618/android-how-to-decode-and-decompile-any-apk-file

Comment: `I'm not able to change the manifest` Do you have the source code?

Comment: no. I have the apk.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called apktool located here

```
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/
```

that may be able to help you. Essentially what it does, is it decompiles the APK file, allowing you to see the files that are inside. Once you decompile the APK, you will see a file called

```
apktool.yml
```

where you can change the version code / version name. The tricky part will now be recompiling the APK back to the original state. Apktool can help with that, as long as you have the keystore file and credentials the original developer used to sign the APK with. If you need any help with the specifics of Apktool, let me know!

Comment: `as long as you have the keystore file and credentials the original developer used to sign the APK with`

what if I don't?

Comment: There's unfortunately not a whole lot that can be done. If you don't have the original keystore, you can sign the APK with a different keystore. This would require you to upload the APK under a different store listing, though.

Comment: the app is used only internally. would it make sense just to delete the original and put this new one in its place. is that even possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can only upload an APK over the current one if it is signed with the same keystore and credentials. The only option I can think of is to start a new listing.